# iOS navigation bar in pure javascript with Brad Birdsall's Swipe 2.0

Tags: javascript, ios, canvas, navigationbar

In pure javascript, I want a navigation bar with pages scrolling horizontally & vertically. The code I have seems to work if the page is handled "gentally".  However, the page becomes mis-aligned fairly easily, especially by dragging the page down into the rubberband zone and scrolling at the same time.

The page is automatically re-aligned by hiding the page (using style.display='none') and redisplaying it or double clicking on the page with the scrollbar over it.

I've done my best to try simulating a double click without my simulated double click having the same effect that manually double clicking does.  (But I am fairly new to javascript, so there is a possibility I missed something there, or it could be some event other than a double that is correcting the problem.)

I tried posting my code here, but ran into a 30000 character limit and I have cut my code down to 32K (including Brad's Swipe 2.0), so I have removed Swipe 2.0 (which is available at https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe).  I have the code also posted at my website, including Swipe 2.0, at http://www.datewise.com/testa.html.  I don't think it makes sense to post the code at jsfiddle because the problem can only be observed on the iPhone (and as far as I know, an iPhone will not execute code at jsfiddle).

As far as I know, it has to be run on an iPhone to see the problem - that is the only thing I have been testing with.  To see the problem, hold the phone in portrait mode.  At the first screen, select a color - e.g., yellow and it will display a yellow page - scroll left & right and see the navigation bar stay.  Carefully, scroll exactly vertically down and back up to the navigation bar.  So far, everything should work fine.

An easy way to create the problem is to rotate the phone landscape, then back to portrait.  While I could handle rotating in the sample code, I haven't to allow the problem to be shown easily and reliably.  You can also get in this problem mode by scrolling diagonally (which is why I specified to "carefully scroll exactly vertically".)  Then, scroll again left and right.  Finally, double click under the navigation bar and the page will fix itself.

To see the problem being fixed by hiding and re-displaying it, use the pointed box in the navigation screen, this only changes the style.display settings.  Then, use the combo box to navigate back to the same page color page (which again is only changing the style.display setting).

I expect one solution seems like immatating either how the double clicking or style.display works by simulating one of my two manual solutions at the end of the anonymous function "end: function(event)".  You can see my attempted solution by looking for the comment "Added to try to fix alignment problem".

Here is a copy of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>

<title>AppTitle</title>
<style type='text/css'>
html, body, div, form {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  font-size:100%;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  background:transparent;
}
.swipe {
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap > div {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}
</style>

<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi' />

<form id='form0' style='position:relative; z-index:100' ontouchmove='BlockMove(event);'>
   <div id='nav' style='z-index:100; position:fixed; width:"320px"; height="44px"; background:black;'>
      <canvas id='navCanvas' width='320px' height='44px'>
         Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
   </div>
</form>

<form id='form1' style='position:relative; z-index:1'>
    <div id='mySwipe' class='swipe'>
        <div class='swipe-wrap'>
            <div>
                <canvas id='canvas1' width='50' height='50'>
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div>
                <canvas id='canvas2' width='50' height='50'>
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div>
                <canvas id='canvas3' width='50' height='50'>
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
                </canvas>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<form id='form3' style='position:relative' ontouchmove='BlockMove(event);'>
   <div id='homeForm'; style='position:relative; height:100%; width:100%; z-index:1' ontouchmove='BlockMove(event);'>
      <div id='d1' style='position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1'>
         <canvas id='homeCanvas' width='400' height='300' style='border:1px solid #d3d3d3'>
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
         </canvas>
      </div>
      <div id='dHomeColorList' style='position:absolute; z-index:2'>
         <select name='homeColorList' id='homeColorList' onChange='homeColorChange()'
             style="font:'20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'; width:140px">
            <option value='Please select'>Please select</option>
            <option value='0'>Yellow</option>
            <option value='1'>Pink</option>
            <option value='2'>Blue</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>

</head>

<body onload='canvasApp()' onunload='closeMe()'>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   var eventHandlerNavBarLaunched = false;
   var fromSchedule='home', saveDisease, saveRequest;
   var FontGrp_Headers='bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
   var FontGrp_SmallHeaders='bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
   var currDisplayType='splash';
   var arrowLeft=0, arrowTop=0, arrowRight=0, arrowBottom=0;

function BlockMove(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
}

function apparentWidth() {
  return screen.availWidth;
}

function apparentHeight() {
   var rtnVal=screen.height;
   if (rtnVal <= 480) {
       rtnVal=480;
   } else if (rtnVal <= 568) {
      rtnVal=568;
   }
  return rtnVal;
}

function closeMe() {
   if (eventHandlerNavBarLaunched) {
      var navCanvas = document.getElementById('navCanvas');
      if (navCanvas.removeEventListener)
         navCanvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', navBarMouseUp, false);
      else if (navCanvas.detachEvent)
         navCanvas.detachEvent('on' + 'mouseup', navBarMouseUp);
      eventHandlerNavBarLaunched=false;
   }       
}

function placeColoredTxt(ctx, fontGroup, left, right, top, bottom, text1, color) {
   var currWidth, currHeight, x, y;
   currWidth=right-left;
   currHeight=bottom-top;
   ctx.font=fontGroup;
   ctx.textAlign='center';
   ctx.fillStyle=color;
   x=Math.floor(left+currWidth/2);
   y=Math.floor(4+top+currHeight/2);
   ctx.fillText(text1,x,y);
}

function canvasApp () {

   var theCanvas, ctx, myCanvas;
   var pageNo;
   var availableWidth, availableHeight;
   var availableWidth;
   var availableHeight;
   var mouseUp={};

   for (j=0; j<=3; j++) {
      drawScreen(j);
   } 

   window.mySwipe = Swipe(document.getElementById('mySwipe'));
   if (!eventHandlerNavBarLaunched) {
      var navCanvas = document.getElementById('navCanvas');
      addEvent(navCanvas, 'mouseup', navBarMouseUp);
      addEvent(navCanvas, 'unload', closeMe);
      eventHandlerNavBarLaunched = true;
   }

   showArea('home', '');

   if (typeof String.prototype.trim != 'function') { // detect native implementation
       String.prototype.trim = function () {
          return this.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
      };
   }

   //---------------------------------------------------------------
   // canvasApp() functions
   function addEvent(target, eventType, eventHandler) {
      if (target.addEventListener)
         target.addEventListener(eventType, eventHandler, false);
      else if (target.attachEvent)
         target.attachEvent('on' + eventType, eventHandler);
   }

   function windowToCanvas(x, y, cnvs)
   {
      var bbox = cnvs.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {x:Math.floor(x-bbox.left * (cnvs.width / bbox.width)),
              y:Math.floor(y-bbox.top * (cnvs.height / bbox.height))
             }
   };

   function navBarMouseUp(e) {
      var loc=windowToCanvas(e.clientY, e.clientX, document.getElementById('navCanvas'));
      e.preventDefault();
      procMouseUp(loc);
   }

   function getMyCanvas(pageNo) {
      switch (pageNo) {
         case 0:
            theCanvas = document.getElementById('homeCanvas');
            ctx = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
            break;
         case 1:    
            theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
            ctx = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
            break;
         case 2:    
            theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
            ctx = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
            break;
         case 3:    
            theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas3');
            ctx = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
            break;
      }
      return ctx;
   }

   function drawScreen(i) {
      var j, fillPage=false;
      pageNo = i;
      ctx = getMyCanvas(pageNo);

      availableWidth = apparentWidth();
      availableHeight= apparentHeight();

      if (i>0 && availableHeight<770) {
         availableHeight=770;
      }

      ctx.canvas.width=availableWidth;
      ctx.canvas.height=availableHeight;

      //ctx.canvas.style.marginLeft='-8px';
      ctx.canvas.style.marginLeft='0px';
      ctx.canvas.style.marginTop='-8px';
      ctx.canvas.style.padding='0 0 0 0';
      ctx.canvas.style.border ='0 0 0 0';
      ctx.canvas.width=availableWidth;
      ctx.canvas.height=availableHeight;

      switch (pageNo) {
         case 0:
            calcHomePage(ctx, availableHeight, availableWidth);
            break;
         case 1:
            ctx.fillStyle='#ff0';

            fillPage=true;

            break;
         case 2:
            ctx.fillStyle='#f0f';

            fillPage=true;

            break;
         case 3:
            ctx.fillStyle='#0ff';

            fillPage=true;

            break;         
      }
      if (fillPage) {
         ctx.rect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
         ctx.fill();

         ctx.fillStyle='#666';
         ctx.font = FontGrp_Headers;
         ctx.textAlign='center';
         for (j=100; j<availableHeight; j+=100) {
            ctx.fillText(j, availableWidth/2, j);
         }
      }
   }
}

function procMouseUp(loc) {
   var pressedButton = '', x, y;
   x = Math.round(loc.x, 0);
   y = Math.round(loc.y, 0);
   if (x>arrowTop & x<arrowBottom & y>arrowLeft & y<arrowRight) {
      switch(fromSchedule) {
         case 'ages':
         case 'Ages':
            switchArea('ages');
            drawNavigation('Home', 'Color Specific');
            break;
         case 'home':
         case 'Home':
            switchArea('home');
            break;
      }
   }
} 

function drawNavigation(fromScrn, currTitle) { // Draw the navigation bar
   var navElement = document.getElementById('navCanvas');
   var navCtx = navElement.getContext('2d');
   var grd;
   var btnLeft=45, btnTop=18, btnHeight=28, btnWidth=50, cornerRadius=5;
   var font = FontGrp_Headers;

   navElement.style.textAlign='center';
   navElement.style.alignmentBaseline='middle';
   navElement.style.zIndex=100;
   navElement.style.display='inline';
   availableWidth = apparentWidth();
   navCtx.canvas.width=availableWidth;
   width = availableWidth-60;

   grd = navCtx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 44);
   grd.addColorStop(0, '#000');
   grd.addColorStop(1, '#000');
   navCtx.fillStyle = grd;
   navCtx.fill();

   if (fromScrn.length > 0) {
      drawArrow(navCtx, fromScrn, btnTop, btnLeft, btnHeight, btnWidth, cornerRadius);
   }
   placeColoredTxt(navCtx, FontGrp_Headers, 100, availableWidth-20, 1, 44, currTitle, '#fff');
   fromSchedule = fromScrn;
}

function calcHomePage(ctx, availableHeight, availableWidth) {  // Calculate the appearance of the home page
   var child = document.getElementById('dHomeColorList');
   var left=140;

   var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,ctx.canvas.height,ctx.canvas.width);
   grd.addColorStop(0,'#58a2e2');
   grd.addColorStop(1,'#1863c0');
   ctx.fillStyle=grd;
   ctx.rect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
   ctx.fill();

   ctx.fillStyle='#fff';
   ctx.fillRect(25,95,availableWidth - 50,availableHeight - 95-2);

   sectionTop = 130;
   line = sectionTop;
   spacing = 44;
   ctx.fillStyle='#000';
   ctx.font = FontGrp_Headers;
   ctx.textAlign='center';
   ctx.fillText('Color Schedules', availableWidth/2, line);
   line += (2/3) * spacing;
   ctx.textAlign='right';
   width = ctx.measureText('Colors').width-20;
   ctx.fillStyle ='#CCC';   

   ctx.fillText('Colors', 50+width, line);
   child.style.top = line-26 + 'px';
   child.style.left= left + 'px';
   line += spacing;   
}

function homeColorChange() {
   var child = document.getElementById('homeColorList');

   if (child.selectedIndex > 0) {
      showArea('ages', 'home');
      mySwipe.slide(child.value, 20); // Open Brad Birdsall's slider at page (child.value)
   }
   child.selectedIndex=0;
}

function switchArea(areaName) {
   var homePage = document.getElementById('homeForm');
   var navPage = document.getElementById('nav');
   var sliderPage = document.getElementById('mySwipe');

   switch (areaName) {
      case 'home':
         homePage.style.display='inline';
         navPage.style.display='none';
         sliderPage.style.display='none';
         window.scrollTo(0,0);
         break;
      case 'ages':
         homePage.style.display='none';
         navPage.style.display='inline';
         sliderPage.style.display='inline';
         window.scrollTo(0,0);
         break;
    }
} 

function showArea(areaName, txtTitle) {
   var currCtx, grd;

   switch (areaName) {
      case 'home':
         switchArea(areaName);
         break;
      case 'ages':
         switchArea(areaName);
         drawNavigation('Home', 'Color Specific');
         break;
      default:
         alert('Unrecognized command passed to showArea, areaName: [' + areadName + ']');
         break;
   }
}

function drawArrow(context, text, top, left, height, width, cornerRadius) {
   // Draw the pointed rectangle box on left side of the navigation bar
   var keyGradient = context.createLinearGradient(left, top, left, top + height);
   var drawingTop=top/2, drawingLeft=left/2;
   keyGradient.addColorStop(0,   'rgb(208, 208, 210)');
   keyGradient.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgb(162, 162, 166)');
   context.save();
   context.fillStyle=keyGradient;
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(drawingLeft-(height/2), (height/2) + drawingTop);  //A
   context.lineTo(drawingLeft, height + drawingTop); //B

   if (cornerRadius>0) {
      context.lineTo(width + drawingLeft - cornerRadius, height + drawingTop); //C
      context.arcTo(width + drawingLeft, height + drawingTop, width + drawingLeft, height + drawingTop - cornerRadius, cornerRadius); //D
      context.lineTo(width + drawingLeft, drawingTop + cornerRadius); //E
      context.arcTo(width + drawingLeft, drawingTop, width + drawingLeft - cornerRadius, drawingTop, cornerRadius); //F
   } else {
      context.lineTo(width + drawingLeft, height + drawingTop); //CD
      context.lineTo(width + drawingLeft, drawingTop); //EF
   }
   context.lineTo(drawingLeft, drawingTop); //G
   context.closePath();
   context.stroke();
   context.fill();
   context.font=FontGrp_SmallHeaders;
   context.fillStyle='#fff';
   context.textAlign='center';
   context.fillText(text, left + (width)/2 - (height/4) - context.measureText(text).width/2, top + (height)/2 - context.measureText('M').width/2);
   context.restore();

   arrowTop=drawingTop;
   arrowLeft=(left/2)-(height/4);
   arrowBottom=drawingTop+height;
   arrowRight=arrowLeft+width;
}

/*
 *
 * Swipe 2.0
 *
 * Brad Birdsall
 * Copyright 2013, MIT License
 * <Get this code at https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe>
 *
*/

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the part of Swipe 2.0 where I tried to put my double click simulation:

```
   end: function(event) {

      // measure duration
      var duration = +new Date - start.time;

      // determine if slide attempt triggers next/prev slide
      var isValidSlide =
            Number(duration) < 250               // if slide duration is less than 250ms
            && Math.abs(delta.x) > 20            // and if slide amt is greater than 20px
            || Math.abs(delta.x) > width/2;      // or if slide amt is greater than half the width

      // determine if slide attempt is past start and end
      var isPastBounds =
            !index && delta.x > 0                            // if first slide and slide amt is greater than 0
            || index == slides.length - 1 && delta.x < 0;    // or if last slide and slide amt is less than 0

      // determine direction of swipe (true:right, false:left)
      var direction = delta.x < 0;

      // if not scrolling vertically
      if (!isScrolling) {

        if (isValidSlide && !isPastBounds) {

          if (direction) {

            move(index-1, -width, 0);
            move(index, slidePos[index]-width, speed);
            move(index+1, slidePos[index+1]-width, speed);
            index += 1;

          } else {

            move(index+1, width, 0);
            move(index, slidePos[index]+width, speed);
            move(index-1, slidePos[index-1]+width, speed);
            index += -1;

          }

          options.callback && options.callback(index, slides[index]);

        } else {

          move(index-1, -width, speed);
          move(index, 0, speed);
          move(index+1, width, speed);

        }

      }

      // kill touchmove and touchend event listeners until touchstart called again
      element.removeEventListener('touchmove', events, false)
      element.removeEventListener('touchend', events, false)

      //---------------------------------------------------------------
      // Added to try to fix alignment problem

       var obj = document.getElementById('form1');
       var clickEvt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
       clickEvt.initEvent("dblclick");
       obj.dispatchEvent(clickEvt);


      // End added code
      //---------------------------------------------------------------

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the initial problem - it was a very simple change to Swipe() that had nothing to do with my earlier proposed solution.  With this fix, my way of reliably generating the problem (rotating the iPhone to landscape and back) always creates the problem and this fix always corrects it, by merely moving the page to the right or left and letting go.

At the very bottom of Swipe was some commented out prototypes.  If I added a call to window.scrollTo() to the one that is called at the end of any animation and the problem occurs, the screen will snap to the correct position at the end of the navigation animation.  Specificlaly, here was my change (uncommenting the transitionEnd function and adding the call to scrollTo()):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
  // startSlide: 4,
  // auto: 3000,
  // continuous: true,
  // disableScroll: true,
  // stopPropagation: true,
  // callback: function(index, element) {},
   transitionEnd: function(index, element) {window.scrollTo(0, 0);}
});
```

Here is a completed sample: http://www.datewise.com/testa1.html